# How to remove the sign before the element

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to get rid of the sign in front of the element, but the symbol variables are involved, so I can't use the `Abs` function to get rid of the sign.

I want this list `{-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3]}` to be processed to `{1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3]}`.

In addition, What should I do when the list contains a ± sign? For example, when the list is `{-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3], -Fx[-3], ±Fy[-2] ,±Fy[±x]}`.

Comment: Related: [(9637)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9637/121), [(26971)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26971/121), [(46004)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46004/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What should I do when the list contains a ± sign? I've updated the question.

Comment: user216, please see my updated answer. @user1066 That's nice! Why not post a formal Answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am sure there are many ways to do this. One possible way could be

```
ClearAll[x,Fx];
expr = {-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3]};
Times[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ /@ expr /. {True -> (-1), False -> 1}, expr]
```

gives

```
 {1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3]}
```

Answer (score 7):

What about

```
expr   /. y_ /; y < 0 -> -y 
(*{1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3]}*)
```

Comment: Clever, but beware something like `-Fx[-1]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard obviously to simple! Other problems arise if you consider expressions like `-g[x]+f[-x]`

Comment: It fits the given example however, and I like terse, so you already have my up-vote. :-)

Comment: Me too, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Not as terse as Ulrich's replacement, but perhaps more robust:

```
list = {-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3], -Fx[-1], +Fx[-1]};

Replace[a : -_ | _?Negative :> -a] /@ list
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3], Fx[-1], Fx[-1]}
> ```

Updated for your latest example:

```
list2 = {-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3], -Fx[-1], +Fx[-1], ±Fy[-2], ±Fy[±x]};

Replace[{a : -_ | _?Negative :> -a, ±a_ :> a}] /@ list2
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3], Fx[-1], Fx[-1], Fy[-2], Fy[±x]}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[removeSigns]

removeSigns = # Sign[#] /. Sign -> (1 &) &;

removeSigns @ {-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3]}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3]}
> ```

Also

```
ClearAll[removeSigns2, removeSigns3, removeSigns4, removeSigns5]

removeSigns2 = Abs[#] /. Abs -> (# &) &

removeSigns3 = ReplaceAll[Abs -> Identity] @* Abs

removeSigns4 = Map[Replace[Abs[x_] :> x]]@*Abs (*thanks: Mr.Wizard *)

removeSigns5 = Function[{x}, If[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[x], -x, x], Listable];
```

Comment: Consider also: `Replace[Abs[x_] :> x] /@ Abs[list]`  -- this would not strip inner appearances of `Abs`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Sqrt[lst lst]//PowerExpand
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3]}

(Originally posted as a comment)

Answer (score 2):

Position-based solutions

1.

```
list = {-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3]};

p = Position[list, _Times | _?Negative, 1];
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> -x, p] @ list
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3]}

2.

```
list = {-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3], -Fx[-1], +Fx[-1], ±Fy[-2], ±Fy[±x]};

p = Position[list, _Times | _?Negative | _PlusMinus, 1];

ReplaceAt[{x_PlusMinus :> x[[1]], x_ :> -x}, p] @ list
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3], Fx[-1], Fx[-1], Fy[-2],
Fy[±x]}

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = {-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3], -Fx[-1], +Fx[-1]};

list2 = {-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3], -Fx[-1], +Fx[-1], ±Fy[-2], ±Fy[±x]};
```

---

Using `Abs`, `FactorList` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
f = Function[a, If[NumericQ@a, Abs@a, 
    FactorList[a /. b_ /; Head[b] === PlusMinus :> b[[1]]][[2, 1]]], Listable];

f@list1

f@list2
```

*Results*:

> {1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3], Fx[-1], Fx[-1]}
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3], Fx[-1], Fx[-1], Fy[-2],
> Fy[±x]}

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
func = (ToBoxes@# /. RowBox[{"-" | "±", a_}] :> a // ToExpression) &;

func@{-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3]}
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3]} *)

func@{-1, -2, +3, 4, -x, +x, -Fx[3], +Fx[3], -Fx[-3], ±Fy[-2], ±Fy[±x]}
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, x, x, Fx[3], Fx[3], Fx[-3], Fy[-2], Fy[±x]} *)
```